# Category 'Legal' on blog.stackoverflow.com produces infinite redirect loop

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

The category selection of blog entries on blog.stackoverflow.com does not work for the category 'legal'. The URL is linked to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/legal/ which produces an inifite redirect loop upon calling the URL.

[image]

Comment: This is probably on purpose, and some elaborate inside joke :D

Comment: @Pekka: you mean as in "legal issues are an neverending story"?

Comment: @Tobias yeah, something like that :)

Comment: `[status-bydesign]` :D

Comment: @KennyTM: [status-IANAL]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect loop on blog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73896/redirect-loop-on-blog)

Comment: ...what?  A recursive problem deserves a recursive solution.

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Can you imagine a world without lawyers?  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0u9JAt6gFqM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed, it was a problem with the redirect add-in.

Comment: Aw, that's too bad.  I sent many an innocent person to that link for legal information regarding stack overflow and its content.