# Blog search by tag will never complete?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, blog

I went to the blog and clicked on one of the tags.  "Legal" to be precise.  It redirected me to this url:

`https://blog.stackoverflow.com/categoryhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.comhttps://stackoverflow.com/legal/`

That's a mouthful.  Anyway, Firefox had this to say about it:

> The page isn't redirecting
> properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server
> is redirecting the request for this
> address in a way that will never
> complete.
>
> *This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
> cookies.

I'm pretty sure I have cookies enabled....

Comment: Legal's the only one in the list that goes into a redirect loop for me.  Strange.

Comment: [repro on Chrome](http://i.imgur.com/75JxW.png)

Comment: This is a [dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66153/category-legal-on-blog-stackoverflow-com-produces-infinite-redirect-loop), actually, but it's not been fixed, so...

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Sorry, I searched but didn't find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed, it was a problem with the redirect add-in.

Comment: Oh, wow, kudos!  I thought this had been forgotten about...