# Redirect loop on blog

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Category 'Legal' on blog.stackoverflow.com produces infinite redirect loop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66153/category-legal-on-blog-stackoverflow-com-produces-infinite-redirect-loop)

The link to the 'legal' category on the blog navigation menu:

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/legal/

Comment: Possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73896/redirect-loop-on-blog

Comment: loooooooooooooooooooool

Comment: Also a dupe of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/blog-search-by-tag-will-never-complete